# Does copying data from Postgres to Bigquery in Cloud Fusion cause columns with Numeric Datatypes to move decimal places?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am copying over 20,000 rows from a table in Postgres to Bigquery. In both Postgres and Bigquery the datatype is Numeric (13,2) or Numeric (12,8) for columns that are Numeric.
It manages to copy over the correct values from Postgres for all the columns except the ones with Numeric datatype. It would move a decimal place or won't capture the full number.

I am not sure if Numeric types are need to be redefined in bigquery or if I need to add a wrapper.

Comment: Is it a postgres on Cloud SQL, or managed externally?